# Calling a JavaScript function several times (ex: myFunc(1,2,3)(1,2)(2); )

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, optional-parameters

I recently encountered something in JavaScript that I have never seen before, and I have no idea what this type of function invocation is called. I want to learn more about how it works.

Say you have a multiply function that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments. The function will return the product of all of those arguments, like so:

```
function multiply() {

    var x = 1;

    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        x *= arguments[i];
    }

    return x;
}
```

Calling multiply(1,2,3) would then return 6.

However, you could change the last line, return x, to return a function that runs the multiplication again if additional parameters are supplied. Therefore, you could do something like:

```
multiply(1,2,3)(1,2)(3)
```

...and you would get 36.

I had no idea this was possible. What is this chaining of function calls together called? Does anyone know where to find additional examples of this?

EDIT!!!

I forgot that the call would really be:

```
mulitply(1,2,3)(1,2)(3)()
```

There's a condition to check if no parameters are present, just to return the current value. This will end the chain of calls.

Comment: read https://leanpub.com/javascriptallongesix/read it's a mind bending book, but well worth the time

Comment: Not exactly, because the final call `(3)` would also return a function. You'd need some additional machinery such as a `.value` method attached to the function to return the value.

Comment: `r = f()()()` is equivalent to `f1 = f(); f2 = f1(); r = f2();`, without intermediate variables - functions-objects are themselves just values, which can be returned. This works / is implemented in JavaScript via _closures_ and _first-class functions_. The online book [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) does a fairly good job of discussing the principles and provides several clean examples.

Comment: terminus technicus: variadic curried function.

Comment: @NinaScholz I believe there is argument against considering this currying..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: @torazaburo you're totally right. I forgot that all uses of this function end in () and there is a condition to check if arguments.length === 0, return the current multiplied total.